# My While Loop Conditions are not being met

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I don't understand why my loop won't stop. It keeps going to the else part when I enter a number between 0 and 300 included.

```
#validar puerta
puerta = ''
lista4 = []
for x in range(0, 301):
    lista4.append(x)
active = True
while active:
    if puerta == 'general' or (puerta in lista4):
        dispositivos.append(puerta)
        active = False
    else:
        puerta = input('Ingrese número de puerta: ')
```

Comment: It works for me when I type `general` at the prompt. It then fails because `dispositivos` is not defined though.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop doesn't stop because when you enter a number through a `input()` function, it is a string, but the numbers list you generated are numbers, so you have to convert the input to numbers using `int()` or convert the numbers in the list to strings using `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
puerta = ""
lista4 = []
for x in range(0, 301):
    lista4.append(x)
active = True
dispositivos=[]

while active:
    if puerta == 'general' or (puerta in lista4):
        dispositivos.append(puerta)
        active = False
    else:
        puerta=input('Ingrese número de puerta: ')
        if puerta.isdigit():
           puerta=int(puerta)
```

Explanation:
You have 2 problems, first one you dont define the array dispositivos, so i defined it.
Second one : when you read the variable puerta , you read a string so when you try to find its value on a integer list it doesnt exist , so you never enter in the first if always stay on the else.
To prevent that when you read the variable puerta you have to check first if its an integer, if it is then cast it to int.